# Using Ruby to wait for a page to load an element

Tags: ruby, watir, wait, watir-webdriver

I currently have a working piece of Ruby that looks like this:

```
 def error_message
    browser.span(:id => 'ctl00_cphMainContent_lblMessage').wait_until_present(30) do
      not errors.empty?
    end
    errors
  end
```

However, I'd prefer something more like this:

```
span(:errors, :id => 'ctl00_cphMainContent_lblMessage')


##farther down##


def error_message
   browser.errors.wait_until_present(30) do 
etc...
```

I'm new to Ruby, but how can I do something like this, assuming it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you make use of the `Watir::Wait.until` or `<element>.wait_until_present` methods.

In this way, you could do something like:

```
# Earlier in code
@browser = Watir::Browser.start('http://mypage.com/')
# ...
errors = { my_first_error: "You forgot your keys in the car!" }

check_for_errors(error[:my_first_error])

# Wherever
def check_for_errors(error, expiry=30)
    error_element = @browser.span(:id => 'ctl00_cphMainContent_lblMessage')
    error_element(value: error).wait_until_present(expiry)
end
```

See the [watir documentation](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) for more information.

Comment: The 'wait_until_present' method works perfectly. The issue is that I have to specify the element every time. I'd much rather re-use something called 'error' or something equally generic than directly specifying 'span(:id => 'blahblahblah') every time I need to wait on that label message.

Comment: If you know the text of every single error you could raise, you could fill a hash with those and search based on the page containing the text (ie: `browser.text.include? errors[:my_first_error]`), but that gets pretty fragile. If you just want to blanket search for errors, you can do `browser.text.include? "Error!"`, replacing "Error!" with whatever text you precede each of your errors by.

Comment: If that helps, can you select an answer?